# How can I retrieve "exception" data from a table without knowing the data in advance?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that updates all the time.
The table maintains a list that links stores to clubs, and manages, among other things, "discount percentages" per store + club.

Table name: Policy_supplier

Column: POLXSUP_DISCOUNT

Suppose all the "vendors" in the table are marked with a 10% discount.
And someone accidentally signs one vendor with 8% or 15% (or even NULL)
How do I generate a query to retrieve the "abnormal" vendor?

Comment: You mean something like `SELECT * FROM Policy_supplier WHERE POLXSUP_DISCOUNT <> 10`?

Comment: To a first approximation, `SELECT * FROM Policy_supplier WHERE POLXSUP_DISCOUNT IN (SELECT TOP (5) POLXSUP_DISCOUNT GROUP BY POLXSUP_DISCOUNT ORDER BY COUNT(*))` could help, as the least common values would stand out. If you need this automated, more care needs to be taken to only select truly exceptional values. (Also, this is slow, sprinkling in windowing is better.)

Comment: First, it is an automatic check.
Second, I do not assume before the test that the discount percentages are 10 ... When the query goes to the table it goes through Policy after policy and for each of them it has to check the "exceptions".
That is, the query will need to identify that the majority are set to X, and then find the Y

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense. First you need to define what is an "abnormal" value, what is the algorithm yo test for that? What happens if someone updates all the values to 99% for example, that's likely abnormal but comparing them with each other would see nothing wrong.

Comment: Okay, here's an edge case:
If I have a policy in 150 suppliers
With 149 defined with 10% discount
And one is set with a 7 percent discount.
Is there no code that can identify it?

Comment: That's not an edge case, that's normal. An edge case would be if they are all updated to a crazy value. You need your own validation rules for that.

Comment: @DavidG the question is valid and quite common, especially in benchmarking and monitoring. When measuring anything you want to know not only the average but which and how many measurements occur outside eg the 5-95% range. If only one record out of 150 is 7%, it's exceptional

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that, I'm just explaining that there are situations where this will fall down as a tool to detect anomalies.

Comment: @DavidG why would it? If you calculate the 95th percentile of discounts, you can check for rows above it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If all discounts were accidentally set to be 95% (clearly an anomaly) then both answers (both good answers IMO) would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the mode of your discounts and then just pick out the records that aren't equal to that mode:

```
WITH mode_discount AS (SELECT TOP 1 POLXSUP_DISCOUNT FROM table GROUP BY POLXSUP_DISCOUNT ORDER BY count(*) DESC)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE POLXSUP_DISCOUNT <> (SELECT POLSXUP_DISCOUNT FROM mode_discount);
```

Comment: It will not help me because the first query can show me the problematic line

Comment: How would the first query pull the problematic line. The first query, the CTE, pulls the POLXSUP_DISCOUNT that occurs the most. By your definition that is the "Correct" discount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) clause with aggregates to calculate an aggregate over a data range and include it in the results. For example,

```
SELECT avg(POLXSUP_DISCOUNT)
from Policy_supplier
```

Would return a single average value while

```
SELECT POLXSUP_DISCOUNT, avg(POLXSUP_DISCOUNT) OVER()
from Policy_supplier
```

Would return the overall average in each row. Typically `OVER` is used with a `PARTITION BY` clause. If you wanted the average per *supplier* you could have written `AVG() OVER(PARTITION BY supplierID)`.

To find anomalies, you should use one of the PERCENTILE functions, eg [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql). For example

```
select PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY POLXSUP_DISCOUNT) over()
from Policy_Supplier
```

Will return a discount value below which you'll find 95% of the records. The other 5% of discounts that are above this are probably anomalies.

Similarly, `PERCENTILE_CONT(0.05)` will return a discount below which you'll find 5% of the records

You can combine both to find *potentially* exceptional records, eg:

```
with percentiles as (
    select ID,
        POLXSUP_DISCOUNT, 
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY POLXSUP_DISCOUNT) over() as pct95,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.05) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY POLXSUP_DISCOUNT) over() as pct05,
from Policy_Supplier)
select ID,POLXSUP_DISCOUNT
from percentiles
where POLXSUP_DISCOUNT>pct95 or POLXSUP_DISCOUNT<pct05
```